# QtSerialPort not writing to serial port

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, g-code, 3d-printing

I am trying to send Gcode commands to a 3d printer with QtSerialPort. I am able to connect and read the startup gcode the printer sends out but I haven't been able to write a Gcode to make the printer do something. I have read many people's code and mine doesnt look wrong as far as I can tell but I am definitely missing something.

This is what I use to connect to the 3d printer:

```
void MainWindow::on_connectButton_clicked()
{
    serial->setPortName(ui->portBox->currentText());
    serial->setBaudRate(250000);
    serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);;
    serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    if (serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
       ui->label->setText("Connected to Printer!!");
    } else {
    ui->label->setText("Error: Failed to connect");
    }
}
```

This is what I am typing to write to the serial port:

```
QString command = "G28";
QByteArray x = command.toLocal8Bit();
serial->write(x);
```

This gives me no errors but the printer doesn't react. I tried the Qt serial console example and sent out "G28" and the printer reacts correctly. on the same program I added a button that executes the above code to write the command and it did nothing. That tells me the problem is likely on how I am writing to the port. 
Anyone have any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to latin1 maybe?

Comment: What is latin1?

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/Basics_of_String_Encoding, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html

Comment: so does adding command.toLatin1(); convert it to latin one? I did that but it dodnt help :(

Comment: are you sending the correct commands to what the device is expecting?

Comment: I'm trying to send G28 as that moves the printer motors. It works on the serial port example that comes with Qt. I send G28 and it moves the printer.

Comment: maybe it needs the \n

Comment: OMG you did it! it was the \n. You are an amazing human being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rafael Posted above, my problem was I was missing \n after G28. Changing it to this solved my issue:

```
QString command = "G28\n";
QByteArray x = command.toLocal8Bit();
serial->write(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar symptom, but different cause. I'm adding it here in case Google  lands anyone else with the same issue on this page.

**On Windows 10 I had to make sure to call `serialPort.waitForBytes(100);` immediately after the `serialPort.write(data);` to ensure the bytes actually made it on the wire**. Otherwise, the `write()` would return the correct number of bytes sent, but nothing was sent on the wire.

I also tried `flush()` but this would only send the first set of data and not work for subsequent calls.